# Tikz error in custom latex environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments

I am trying to create an example box as an environment, but when I compile the main text I get

! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.536 \end{example}

I don't know where the missing semicolon is, as all of the tikz commands used have the semicolon at the end. Not sure if I'm missing something, and I'd be grateful if someone could find where I did wrong.

Thanks

```
\newtcolorbox{example}[1] {blanker, enhanced, breakable, before skip = 5mm, after skip = 5mm, 
left=3mm, right=3mm, top=10mm, bottom=3mm, colback=white, 
colframe=cor1, width=162mm, toprule=1pt, bottomrule=1pt, 
rightrule=1pt, leftrule=1pt, outer arc = 8mm, arc = 8mm, sharp corners 
= northwest, sharp corners = southeast, sharp corners = southwest,
title={{\boxfont EXEMPLO}\hspace{3.5mm} \textcolor{gray!80!black} 
{\Large\extitlefont\capitalisewords{#1}}}, 
boxed title style={empty, sharp corners}, 
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-1.3 mm , yshift=-7.3mm},
underlay boxed title ={

% Draw the title underlay rectangle
\fill[cor1!30] ($(frame.north west) + (0,-.3mm)$) rectangle 
($(title.north east)+(-.8mm,-6mm)$ coordinate (R));

% Filldraw the darker fancy in front of the rectangle and behind the 
Example. The coordinates should be better chosen.
\fill[cor1] (frame.north west) -- ($(title.south west) + (1.3mm,0)$) -- ++ (18mm,0mm) arc [start angle=-90, end angle=0, x radius = 2mm, y radius = 2mm] -- ($(frame.north west) + (20mm,0)$) --  cycle;
}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The error is due to a misplaced `)`. Replace `\fill[cor1!30] ($(frame.north west) + (0,-.3mm)$) rectangle 
($(title.north east)+(-.8mm,-6mm)$ coordinate (R));` by `\fill[cor1!30] ($(frame.north west) + (0,-.3mm)$) rectangle 
($(title.north east)+(-.8mm,-6mm)$) coordinate (R);`.

Comment: If you are wondering, why: `calc` expects a closing bracket after `$` but you put `coordinate` there.